# Javascript: Escape <> for non-html strings, but preserve html

Tags: javascript, html, escaping

I have some text that contains HTML (to be rendered in the browser), as well as arbitrary strings with `<>`.  Is there a way to escape those arbitrary tags, but preserve the HTML?  If it helps, the HTML being parsed is very strictly governed, and only a subset of tags is allowed (`b`, `i`, `strong`, `br`)

For example. Given this text:

```
<strong>Foobar</strong> <some other whatever>
```

I need

```
<strong>Foobar</strong> &lt;some other whatever&gt;
```

Comment: as one can add own custom elements nowadays (or in near future) it will be quite hard for the script to decide, what is a HTML tag and what is not. In your example `<some>` could be a valid HTML tag as well with two (empty) attributes `other` and `whatever`.

Comment: In order to do that, you'd have to be able to distinguish valid HTML tags from other things enclosed in angle-brackets. As the spec has become very flexible in that regard, this may be impossible when working with HTML 5.

Comment: I don't know what are you trying to accomplish, but it should be good to not mix things...is it possible to change the arbitrary string delimiter to something different like `{some other wathever}`.....

Comment: We have very strict controls over the HTML we're parsing; only a subset of tags are allowed.

Comment: _"We have very strict controls over the HTML we're parsing; only a subset of tags are allowed."_ Is the subset list of allowed tags stored in an array or object?

Comment: Once the javascript gets it, yes. I'm not sure how the engine that gives us the text handles it.

Comment: Can you include list of allowed tags at Question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cheap option would be to replace `<>` with placeholders, and then restore them in "good" contexts:

```js
allowedTags = ['strong', 'em', 'p'];

text = '<strong>Foobar</strong> <some other whatever> <b>??</b> <em>hey</em>'

text = text
  .replace(/</g, '\x01')
  .replace(/>/g, '\x02')
  .replace(new RegExp('\x01(/?)(' + allowedTags.join('|') + ')\x02', 'g'), "<$1$2>")
  .replace(/\x01/g, '&lt;')
  .replace(/\x02/g, '&gt;')

console.log(text)
```

A not-so-cheap, but more correct solution is to use an (event driven) html parser and escape unwanted stuff as you go.